# Raspberry Pi 3 B+ OpenMediaVault transfer speed capped to 11MB/sec

Tags: raspberry-pi3, nas

So I bought the new Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and installed OMV to use it as a simple home NAS. Everything is working perfectly except that the max speed is just 11MB/sec.

[image: Teracopy]

Just wondering if that's normal? Because The RPi 3 B+ already has a Gigabit Ethernet which supposed to be much faster. Where could the bottleneck be?

Also on OMV you can see that the eth0 speed is labeled as 100Mbits/sec

[image: OMV]

I'm using a WD My Passport 2TB for the storage BTW.

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on [raspberrypi.se]

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out that the botton one says megabits, and the top says megabyte. 100 megabit is 12.5 megabyte, which means you're just 1.5 MB away from the max speed, which is acceptable depending on your computer's drive speed

Comment: Two things that you can look into.
1. according to the datasheet the rpi 3 B+ has a  `Gigabit Ethernet over USB 2.0 (maximum throughput
300Mbps) ` so it should be detected as 1000 Mbits/sec, if not check the cable, also the cable length and the switch you plugged it in. 
2. the 2TB hdd you mentioned should be sharing the SAME usb2.0 connection to the rpi, so the bandwith is split between those two. try reading/writing from/to the interal sd card instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still on the usb 2.0 bus Juan, which is sharing the bus with you passport hd.

Answer (score -1):

The bottleneck is the 100Mbit Ethernet. This is the reason for the 11MB/s.
It's even written into the image: [Raspberry Pi is a slow NAS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFBhG.png)
Therefore I changed from Raspberry Pi 3 to a rock64. It has Gigabit Ethernet + USB 3.

Comment: The 3 B+ has gigabit ethernet. The reason there's a cap is because it's over USB 2, which means you'd max out at ~300Mbps assuming nothing else on the bus and sending data from RAM. https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/